# Communicate my cell phone with my laptops in cell phone frequency?

Tags: gsm, 3g

Every communication that is made without cable, everybody can listen but not everybody can understand. So, when I call someone with my phone, or send a sms my cellp phone send information, I want that my pc know this (I know that both have to the same frequency). Or some site or material to start with it. I have an android.

It's like make a operator communication, just that is my cell phone with my pc and not my cell phone with the operator

Comment: Do you want to trace/snoop/record the communication between phone and mobile network? Do you want to use the computer to transport traffic from/to the phone, i.e. have the computer act as a phone?

Comment: No i dont. I just want comunicate the phone with a pc. And is this the way that the companies does the comunication. I want this because im trying to make telecomunication cheap or free. In to many countries is very expensive. I know programming and how make this work. But i dont know this basic thing of telecomunication. I think how i says, that is the way the companies make the comunication. A cell phone comunicate with the tower(PC, device), tower to the central, central to other tower and tower to the destination cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [OpenBTS](http://wush.net/trac/rangepublic). It is an (experimental) open source implementation of a BTS (base transceiver station), the network node that handles the radio communication. Similar [OpenBSC](http://openbsc.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/OpenBSC).

What you want to do is huge. You will need special hardware.